# Take mean of rows with same condition

Tags: r

In my data frame below I would like to take the mean of `RowMeansCollapsed` and `RowStDev` for rows where `RowNamesLengthCollapsed` is the same. THis will produce an output data frame with only unique `RowNamesLengthCollapsed`.

```
> head(RowMeans_Names)
                  RowNamesCollapsed RowMeansCollapsed         RowStDev RowNamesLengthCollapsed
1  GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCCT  38.2083333333333 140.255174717683                      32
2            AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC            3.5625 6.62977732419582                      22
3            TCTTAACCCGGACCAGAAACTA              3.25 7.10226057415228                      22
4             CTGACCTATGAATTGACAGCC           29.1875 110.206439061093                      21
5            TACCCTGTAGAACCGAATTTGT  46.6041666666667 161.866772973895                      22
6 GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTTATCACGTTCGCCT          41.96875 148.825680659234                      33
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [‹dplyr›](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html), this is trivial:

```
RowMeans_Names %>%
    group_by(RowNamesCollapsed) %>%
    summarize(RowMeansCollapsed = mean(RowMeansCollapsed),
              RowStDev = mean(RowStDev),
              RowNamesLengthCollapsed = first(RowNamesLengthCollapsed))
```

Comment: this produced only NAs

Comment: @user2300940 Do you have NAs in your data? Because then that’s why. You may need to add the `na.rm = TRUE` argument to the calls to `mean` — but be careful with this: the presence of NAs in your data might require special treatment. If there are no `NA`s in the original data, this code doesn’t produce `NA`s.

Comment: @user2300940 yes, it does. Just try it out yourself, replacing `RowMeans_Names` with `head(RowMeans_Names)` in my answer.

Comment: 47: In mean.default(structure(146L, .Label = c("100.416666666667",  ... :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: @user2300940 … your column data type is `character` or `factor`, not `numeric`. Convert it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might help you .

```
df2 <- aggregate(cbind(RowMeansCollapsed, RowStDev) ~ RowNamesCollapsed, df, mean)
```